# How do I configure the email server in Alfresco Activiti?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, war, activiti

Can someone explain to me *which* file I need to update with my email server parameters? The documentation appears to give me 3 configuration-dependent options, but doesn't help me with guidance for the default install.

From the doc:

> The Alfresco Activiti BPM Suite is configured through a properties file named activiti-app.properties. This file must be on the classpath to be found. The following options are possible in relation to this properties file:
>
> An activiti-app.properties file with default values can be found in the WAR file (or exploded WAR folder) in the WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/activiti-app folder.
>   An activiti-app.properties file with custom values can be placed on the classpath. For example: the WEB-INF/classes folder of the WAR, the /lib folder of Tomcat or other places specific to the web container being used.
>
> The values of a configuration file on the classpath have precedence over the values in the WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/activiti-app/activiti-app.properties file.
>
> For the Alfresco Activiti BPM Suite’s web user interface there is an additional configuration file named app-cfg.js. This file is located inside the .war file’s script directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `activiti-app.properties` files, which are present in 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\activiti\tomcat\lib`